# Want to read .txt file and load it into a 2D array, and then print it as is

Tags: java

Working on an assignement where I have to read a .txt file and place it into a 2D array as is. **Note ts HAS TO BE A 2D ARRAY.**

I then have to print it like it is again.

The .txt input looks like this:

```
WWWSWWWW\n
WWW_WWWW\n
W___WWWW\n
__WWWWWW\n
W______W\n
WWWWWWEW\n
```

Here's the code I have currently, I have an error that says that it cannot resolve method 'add'. Probably has to do with the array initializer

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

  Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("D:/trabalho/maze.txt"));
  String[][] list = new list[][];
  while (s.hasNextLine()){
      list.add(s.nextLine());

  }
  s.close();
  System.out.println(list);


}
```

Then the print output has to be

```
WWWSWWWW
WWW_WWWW
W___WWWW
__WWWWWW
W______W
WWWWWWEW
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: As @Berger an array has no `add` Method you should use a ArrayList or just don't use `add` for your array.

Comment: Then how am I supposed to add the .txt input to the array?

Comment: Don't call variables `list`, you should give it a name that provides context to its purpose both for our sake and yours

Comment: `for(int i = 0; s.hasNextLine(), i++){
    list[i]= s.nextLine();
}`

Comment: also you can't initilize a `String[][]` with `List[][]` these are 2 different data types

Comment: Also keep in mind it has to be a 2D array

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna stick with your Array a possible solution would be

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

  Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("D:/trabalho/maze.txt"));
  String[][] list = new String[10][5];
  for(int x = x; s.hasNextLine();x++ ){
   for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
      list[x][i] = s.nextLine();
   }
 }
  s.close();
  System.out.println(list);

}
```

So you don't even need a 2D array Here because the `String` Class acts like an char Array in C++.

Another solution would be to use ArrayLists

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

  Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("D:/trabalho/maze.txt"));
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>;
  while (s.hasNextLine()){
      list.add(s.nextLine());
  }
  s.close();
  System.out.println(list);
}
```

So now you have a list that grows with your amount of Data and also you can just use add Method.
the line `ArrayList<String>` means that your arrayList just can store data from class String

Comment: I do need it to be a 2D array.

Comment: Something like this?

Comment: would be easier if you say us why it has to be a 2D array so we know what to do with it ^^

Comment: I have to store it in a 2D array since I need to do more stuff with it later on :D I need to draw an interface and more classes later on that reads the string in the 2D array so it can draw a maze from the string that's in there.

Comment: Oke so I edited my answere and hope I hope now it may help you

Comment: 'Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
'

Comment: In what line was this thrown?
I think it comes from your Scanner or probably one of the counter variables got to big for your array (But normaly this would cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the reason for using 2D array is that each character is saved in a separate String object.
In case we know absolutely nothing regarding the text file, I would implement like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  File textFile = new File("D:/trabalho/maze.txt");
  Scanner rowsCounter = new Scanner(textFile));

  int rows=0;
  while (rowsCounter.hasNextLine()) {
    rowsCounter.nextLine();
    rows++;
  }
  String[][] data = new String[rows][];

  Scanner reader = new Scanner(textFile);
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    String line = reader.nextLine();
    data[i] = new String[line.length()];
    for (int j = 0; j < line.length(); j++) {
      data[i][j] = line.substring(j, j+1);
    }
  }

  reader.close();
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      System.out.print(data[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

This implementation can handle unknown number of lines and unknown length of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
public static void main(String[] str){

    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new File("path\\text.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      while (s.hasNextLine()){
          list.add(s.nextLine());

      }
      s.close();
      Iterator<String> itr= list.listIterator();

      while(itr.hasNext()){
          System.out.println(itr.next().toString());
      }

}
```

Comment: has to be a 2D array